# Table Reach 4GB and mysql lost connection every connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, blob, innodb, long-integer

I have table that using longblob type, now it is 4GB reach, and every connect to that table, connection Lost. it is local database on 32bit windows 7, mysql server 5.7. using INNODB engine

pls any one help.
 what should i do

Comment: I would guess your blob is too large to fit in `max_allowed_packet`. You can review other causes of lost connections here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Comment: thank you, i moved the backup to 64 bit os windows and can run now but all long blob cannot read.. i have backup from mysql dump but not help

Comment: How big is the biggest blob?  What is the value of `max_allowed_packet`?